# How do I interpret this bash/awk syntax?

Tags: bash, awk

I am making a sincere effort to master bash. 
What would a line like below mean ?

```
ps -ef | awk '/ora_pmon_/ && !/awk/'
```

Thank you.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with `bash`. You have a POSIX-standard pipeline connecting two external commands.

Comment: While tutorials are off-topic for S.O., maybe if you edit your Q to indicate which parts you do understand, and which parts are causing you trouble, as you have some code, we can help you understand it. As the code is mostly `awk` , I refer you to http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awik.html . Good luck.

Comment: It means the same thing as `ps -fp \`pgrep -f ora_pmon_\``.

Answer (score 2):

This means as follows.

```
ps -ef | awk '/ora_pmon_/ && !/awk/'
```

You are first getting the output of `ps -ef` which will have information of all processes running. Then by using a <pipe> (`|`) we send this output to the standard input of the `awk` command.

`awk` will check for lines, basically process names, having the string `ora_pmon` in them AND NOT the string `awk`. The latter is to exclude the process of this command which we do not want in output.

The correct way to do what you want though is just:

```
ps -ef | awk '/[o]ra_pmon_/'
```